# Generate web form with low/no coding, from existing REST and POST URLs

Tags: web-apps, web-development, rest

My team and I are building REST Api's for various systems we have in our office. One thing we don't like doing is building a web interface to be able to test these variaous Api's as we go. Even though they're thrown together, it is not something we really have time for. Eventually our Api's will be used in other teams and projects (Web / Desktop / Mobile).

What I'm hoping to find is a web application that allows us to create menu items, create pages / tables for display, and forms for entry / edit. The easier and quicker the better.
It would need to allow us to provide an REST Api URL for where to get the data from, and where to Post back to.

It doesn't need to be pretty, it just need to allow us to use our REST Api's as we're developing them, so we can make sure they work, and all of the server side functions they trigger work.

Comment: How is your REST API developed? If you haven't used a particular framework or standard, a tool will probably not be able to figure it out.

Comment: It's a standard REST API, it accepts JSON in / out.

Comment: Did you write a formal machine-readable specification for your REST API, for instance in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSDL or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language?

Comment: We are ok with telling the application "These are the properties we want showing up in the list", or "These are the properties / data types we want to show in the form". We just really don't want to waste time building the HTML/CSS/JS.